# unexpected 'use' (T_USE) when trying to use composer

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

So, I am trying to use the coinbase API. I'm attempting a simple test to see if I can make it work, but I'm getting various composer errors.

Currently, I am getting unexpected t 'use' for this code:

```
            use Coinbase\Wallet\Client;
            use Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration;

            $apiKey = 'public';
            $apiSecret = 'private';
            $configuration = Configuration::apiKey($apiKey, $apiSecret);
            $client = Client::create($configuration);
            $spotPrice = $client->getSpotPrice();
            echo $spotPrice;
```

So, are my use statements in the wrong place? Ive tried them outside the index function and outside the class. Both yield completely different sets of results than this.

Outside of the Keks class, I get

> Fatal error: Class 'Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration' not found in
>   /home/content/61/11420661/html/beta/application/controllers/keks.php
>   on line 15

And inside the class but outside the index() function I get

> Fatal error: Trait 'Coinbase\Wallet\Client' not found in >/home/content/61/11420661/html/beta/application/controllers/keks.php on line 4

Is there something wrong in my composer.json maybe?

The full controller is here: http://pastebin.com/4BjPP6YR

Comment: Which version of php do you use? In case of doubt try `<?php echo phpversion();`

Comment: Then please run `<?php echo phpversion();` to get the version.

Comment: oh and by the way: The actual error message is `parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)` or is it something else? (If it is: what is _before_ the code snippet you've posted?)

Comment: The exact message is at the end of this, the code is exactly what I've shown in the pastbin link    "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in /home/content/61/11420661/html/beta/application/controllers/keks.php on line 9"

Comment: I like this answer which includes link to docs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46788263/1767412

Answer (score 87):

You cannot use "use" where you are using it.

The "use" keyword is either in front of a class definition to import other classes/interfaces/traits into it's own namespace, or it is inside the class (but not inside a method) to add traits to the class.

```
<?php
namespace Foo;

use Different\Class; // use can go here

class Bar {
  use TraitCode; // use can go here

  public function baz() {
    $this->traitFunction('etc');
    // use CANNOT go here
  }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. `use` (in this case) has nothing to do with classes, and it doesn't need to be "in front of a class" at all.

Comment: @deceze Look at the pastebin provided in the question, and you'll admit that this answer is reasonably accurate enough in this context.

Comment: In my case taking use statement to the top of the page solve the problem.

Comment: Or, as we say in Joisey, "Youze can't use "use" the way youze is using it."

Answer (score 17):

I'm using CodeIgniter when I try to use "use" keyword it's throwing the error within a method.

I just moved it above the class declaration.

```
<?php
  defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
  use Auth0\SDK\Auth0;
  
  class Home extends CI_Controller {

  }
?>
```

It's working fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can also -

```
public function index() {
    ...
    $configuration = Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration::apiKey($apiKey, $apiSecret);
    $client = Coinbase\Wallet\Client::create($configuration);
    ...
}
```

If you wish to use class inside function and not declare it globally.