# PHP use keyword is causing 500 server error

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm trying to implement PhpPresentation to convert some files, so I have the following code:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\src\PhpPresentation\PhpPresentation;
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\src\PhpPresentation\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\src\PhpPresentation\Style\Color;
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\src\PhpPresentation\Style\Alignment;
```

For some reason exactly this piece of code is causing 500 Internal server error. I have error reporting set to all, but no errors are shown. The path is right, i have the PhpOffice folder in my root directory(public_html) and the corresponding subfolders too.

autoloader code is loaded this way:

```
require_once 'PhpOffice/PhpPresentation/src/PhpPresentation/Autoloader.php';
  \PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Autoloader::register();
  require_once 'PhpOffice/src/Common/Autoloader.php';
  \PhpOffice\Common\Autoloader::register();
```

Comment: Take a look into your http servers error log file, that is where you can read what the actual issue is.

Comment: Most likely those definitions cannot be found by your auto loader.

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected 'use'` on the first use line. Here is my full function https://codeshare.io/aYAdzL

Comment: a few ideas: are there any lines before the `use` lines? maybe one with a missing `;`? and just to be sure...what is your PHP version?

Comment: Ok, that means most likely your php version is outdated and below `5.6`. You want to upgrade.

Comment: I'm not missing a semicolumn and my PHP version is 5.6. The full error is `syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue fixed, thanks to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33355711/7926703

I was using 'use' inside a function which is wrong and error-causing.