# Aws php sdk for S3 client

Tags: aws-php-sdk

I have installed aws-php-sdk via composer into my project, I am using the php version 7.4

I tried below code into my project

I am getting the error syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) [file] =

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This probably means you're putting a use statement where it's not syntactically allowed, for instance inside of a method.  If you're using a trait, try moving it to the top of the class just after the opening bracket.  If you're using a class, then try placing it just before the class declaration.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

[unexpected 'use' (T_USE) when trying to use composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342994/unexpected-use-t-use-when-trying-to-use-composer)