# Using a PHP use keyword conditionally Twilio Programmable SMS

Tags: php, twilio

Looked around and can't really find an answer.

I have a web app that is sending SMS messages using the Twilio SDK

Some installs have Twilio installed and some do not.

I want this code to run only if the Twilio files exist.

The regular code is:

```
require_once ABSPATH.'php/vendor/twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
```

I have tried

```
if(file_exists(ABSPATH.'php/vendor/twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php')) {
    require_once ABSPATH.'php/vendor/twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php';

    use Twilio\Rest\Client;
}
```

and also

```
if(file_exists(ABSPATH.'php/vendor/twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php')) {
    require_once ABSPATH.'php/vendor/twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php';
}
if(class_exists(Twilio\Rest\Client)) {
    use Twilio\Rest\Client;
}



if(file_exists(ABSPATH.'php/vendor/twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php')) {
    require_once ABSPATH.'php/vendor/twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php';

}

use Twilio\Rest\Client;
```

and always get

> syntax error, unexpected 'use'

Is there a way to make this conditional?

Comment: can you show us where this code lives in relation to the class definition?

Comment: To quote an answer in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342994/unexpected-use-t-use-when-trying-to-use-composer, "The "use" keyword is either in front of a class definition to import other classes/interfaces/traits into it's own namespace, or it is inside the class (but not inside a method) to add traits to the class."

Comment: The class definition is loadd in the autoload file just above

Comment: This is at the top of my file, Its just not all installs wwill have the twilio files, so only want to load this class if the files are there

Comment: the code that loads the class is the require_once()  Then if(class_exists(...  will tell you whether it's there or not. You don't use 'use' to decide that. You already know.

Comment: Some of the installs do not have these files. So the require once is conditional....

Comment: Why don't you just `exit` if the file doesn't exist, then continue normally in the rest of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use `use` unconditionally?

```php
 <?php
 use Twilio\Rest\Client;

 if (is_file(ABSPATH.'php/vendor/twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php')) {
      require_once ABSPATH.'php/vendor/twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php';
 }
```

I can run this code without any issue.

Probably risking name conflicts with `Twilio\Rest\Client` but I think you'd have this either way.

Comment: Any explanation why putting the use before works and not after?

Comment: @user3404390 I can only quote [php](https://www.php.net/) itself on this: `The use keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the global scope) or inside namespace declarations. This is because the importing is done at compile time and not runtime, so it cannot be block scoped.` this is what the [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) had to say about it.

Comment: @user3404390 It's a design choice made by the PHP developers. They could've made it work with block scoped `use` keywords I'm sure but there are very good reasons not to do this. You (as an end user) just have to accept this.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time marco-a

Answer (score 0):

Thank you marco-a

Ended up using

```
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

 if (file_exists(ABSPATH.'php/vendor/twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php')) {
      require_once ABSPATH.'php/vendor/twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php';
 }
```

Still not sure why putting the use statement before works, but it does lol

Comment: `use` appears to be conditional by nature ie. (declaring `use Not/A/Path;` is never "verified"/is inactive until your code calls `new Path` somewhere. There are reasons `use` must generally be "on top" or "outside" its container/area of use, not the least of which is accessibility/ease of management. The including of the file can be done anywhere before the class is initiated, again for ease of management/editability that's probably why it generally is placed along with the relevant `use` statement where it is.